# In which assembly I find namespace 'NHibernate.Proxy.Poco.Castle'?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, castle

In which assembly I find namespace 'NHibernate.Proxy.Poco.Castle'? I can find in NHibernate.dll the Proxy.Poco, but not Proxy.Poco.Castle... (using Nhibernate 2.1.2.4000).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's quite old; in recent versions the namespace is `NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle`, and it's in NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.dll